# in powershell, splatting Update-TypeData giving error ScriptMethod not recognized

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering why the following code gives me the error: "ScriptMethod" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I look in the dotnet documentation for this field and it says:

```
-MemberType
Specifies the type of the member to add or change.

Use this parameter with the TypeName, MemberType, Value and SecondValue parameters to add or change a property or method of a type. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

AliasProperty
CodeMethod
CodeProperty
Noteproperty
ScriptMethod
ScriptProperty
For information about these values, see PSMemberTypes Enumeration.
```

Here's the code with the error:

```
$proto = @{
    Force = $true
    TypeName = "System.String"
    MemberName = "RegexCount"
    MemberType = ScriptMethod
    Value = {
        param([regex]$Regex)
        $Regex.Matches($this).Count
    }
}

Update-TypeData @proto
```

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

Replace `MemberType = ScriptMethod` with:

- either: `MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'`
- or: `MemberType = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]::ScriptMethod`

---

According to PowerShell's [parsing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), `ScriptMethod` in your hash-table entry, 
`MemberType = ScriptMethod`, is parsed in *argument* (command) mode, i.e. the *unquoted* `ScriptMethod` token is interpreted as the *name of a command* - and since no such command (typically) exists, you got an error.

You need *expression* mode, in which *string literals* such as `ScriptMethod` must be *quoted* in order to be recognized as such.

By contrast, the [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) *key* names, e.g. `MemberType`, only require quoting if they contain metacharacters such as spaces.

The [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata) target parameter, `-MemberType` is ultimately of enumeration type [`[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes), so you may pass such an enumeration value explicitly, as shown above, but that is verbose and generally not necessary, because PowerShell automatically converts *strings* to and from enumeration types as needed.